# Jquery make two functions run together

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a search button, in which I want to change the icon as well as the color of the border at the same time when it is being clicked on:

```
$(function () {
    $("#search").click(function () {
        $("#search").css({ "border": "2px", "border-style": "ridge", "border-color": "#000000" })
    });

    $("#search").click(function () {
        $("#search").replaceWith($('<img>', { src: 'Icons/magnifier.png' }))
    });
});
```

Right now, my two functions work individually, but when I combine the two, like in my example, only the last one fires.

Is there a way in which I can combine the two functions, so that both the border and the image changes when I click on it?

CSS for the box:

```
.topnav img {
    border: 2px ridge #7ab5dc;
    position: relative;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    float: right;
    margin-top:15px;
    margin-right:20px;
    padding:3px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

HTML

```
       <div class="topnav">
            <img id="search" class="search" src="Icons/magnifier2.png" />
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) When you call `.replaceWith($("<img>"), ...)`, you don't keep the id of search to your image.

**Update:** `.replaceWith($("<img id='search'>"), ...)`

2) Before I edited my answer, I already gave you this advice.

```
$(function(){

  var search = $('#search');

  search.click(function(){
    search.replaceWith(...).css(...);
  });

});
```

That way, your code will only reach into the DOM once to fetch your HTML. This is for a great performance and it also makes sure you are using the element you intended to.

3) You also asked about fading in/out. You can use jQuery's `fadeIn(duration, completeCallback)` and `fadeOut(duration, completeCallback)` functions. Duration is in milliseconds and the callback is an anonymous function, but you could also call another function.

`$("#search").fadeIn(400, function(){ alert("Faded in"); });`

Comment: Thank you for your answer
Whats the pros for declaring a variable? wouldnt that most likely be convenient if i do a conditional expression or a loop?

Comment: The benefit of using the variable is that your code only reaches into the HTML one time instead of multiple times. That means that your code is more efficient and also more reliable, because when you reference a variable, you can be certain the DOM won't be updated or changed and causing your selector to fail.

Comment: Tried chaining them, however no impact, still the same issue. Can it be that the issue occurs because i did a CSS on it in my stylesheet?

Comment: You can try commenting out your stylesheet CSS for that element and try running the jQuery. Did you also try chaining with a variable DOM element, might also help?

Comment: If i comment it out all the properties (with, height border) will be lost, there must be a way to do it even with a css set onload. 
to be honest, i'm trying to learn Jquery on my own, and im not sure that i can do it correctly.

Comment: That is okay, I will help you. Declare a variable like 'var search = $("#search");' then you replace all other pieces of code like "$("#search")" with 'search'

Comment: i declared the var and i can see that it responds to my actions. however it still only changes the icon. Again, i dont think it has anything to do with the predefined CSS, as i can still remove the .replaceWith and get the border to change.

Comment: Try to add the call to .replaceWith after the variable like 'var search = $(...).replaceWith(...)'

Comment: hmm, now nothing at all changes. 
I guess its correct to add it after the search.click(function () right?

Comment: Correct, my bad. I will follow up on this as soon as I get home, then I can try to reproduce. In the meantime, could you edit your post with HTML, CSS and jQuery example of the search bar? Might help solving the problem.

Comment: will do, thank you very much :-) 
- is it complicated to do a fade on it as well?

Comment: Not at all! You just have to call 'element.fadeIn(options);' or similar functions.

Comment: i might try to work on that as you get home. Again thank you very much for helping me out here, it really takes some time getting the hang of it.

Comment: Let's move this discussion to [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95731/jeppe--jquery)

Comment: search.replaceWith($("<img id='search'>", { src: "Icons/magnifier2.png" })).css({ "border": "2px", "border-style": "ridge", "border-color": "#000000" })});

I cant join your chat unfortunately, but following changes the image to a white square, and the border is still not changing :( 
- i made sure that the path to the image is correct. and tried to change some of the ' ", but nothing changes in what see.

Comment: You could also write src=... in the first argument of replaceWith, in the HTML.

Comment: search.replaceWith($("<img id='search' src='Icons/magnifier.png' >"))

It seems to work like this, however it still doesnt include the css after.

Answer (score 4):

This is happening because the second time you declare `$("#search").click(function () { ...` you are overwriting the first function. So, just put everything you want to happen in the same `.click` function

You'll also need semicolons after each line.

As per @jbehrens94's note about the ID being lost, here is my final code

```
$("#search").click(function () {
    $(this).replaceWith($('<img id="search">', { src: 'Icons/magnifier.png' })).css({ "border": "2px", "border-style": "ridge", "border-color": "#000000" });
});
```

Comment: $(function () {
            $("#search").click(function () {
                $("#search").css({ "border": "2px", "border-style": "ridge", "border-color": "#000000" });
                $("#search").replaceWith($('<img>', { src: 'Icons/magnifier.png' }));
            });
        })
Right now my function is as follows. however it still doing the same?

Comment: Ah, I glanced over the fact that you are using `replaceWith`. Try putting that line before the `css` line. I'll update my answer

Comment: is it however incorrect to use replaceWith? 
- next step is to give it a slide out function with a textbox, so that people can make searches. if you catch my drift.

Comment: It should be fine, but `replaceWith` basically removes the element and inserts the new content that you are specifying. This means that it was erasing the changes that you were making to the CSS

Comment: still the same issue though. as @jbehrens94 mentions, would it be that i should chain them?

Comment: Hm. No harm in trying it, just make sure `replaceWith` comes first

Answer (score 0):

@Jeppe I have just tried in different way

```
.topnav img{
    border: 2px ridge #7ab5dc;
    position: relative;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    float:right;
    margin-top:15px;
    margin-right:20px;
    padding:3px;
    border-radius: 5px;

}

.border-change{
    border: 2px ridge #000000 !important; 

}
```

Your Html

```
<div class="topnav">
            <img id="search" class="search" src="Icons/magnifier2.jpg" />
        </div>
```

New One line jquery

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
$("#search").click(function () {
     $("#search").addClass("border-change").attr("src","Icons/magnifier.jpg");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

There was alot of posts in this thread, and i just want to post the code that is working for me, to the users who might have the same problem:

```
    $(function () {
        var search = $("#search");

        search.click(function () {
            search.attr("src", "Icons/magnifier.png").css({ "border": "2px", "border-style": "solid", "border-color": "#808080", "padding-left": "130px", "transition": "all 500ms" });
        });
        $('html').click(function (e) {
            if (e.target.id != 'search') {
                $("#search").attr("src", "Icons/magnifier2.png");
                $("#search").removeAttr('style');;
            }
        });
    })
```

Comment: The .removeAttr in the end, removes any stored CSS code, so that the hover effects etc. still can be applied after the function has fiered.

Answer (score -1):

You Can just Include to actions in single code
like this

$("#search").click(function () {

```
    $("#search").css({ "border": "2px", "border-style": "ridge", "border-color": "#000000" }).replaceWith($('<img>', { src: 'Icons/magnifier.png' }));
});
```

or may be use

$("#search").click(function () {

```
    $("#search").css({ "border": "2px", "border-style": "ridge", "border-color": "#000000" }).html($('<img>', { src: 'Icons/magnifier.png' }));
});
```

Comment: Neither of them work, it still only changes the magnifing glass.